# Horizontal layout scroll animation

Tags: html, css, angularjs, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using a [ng-repeat 1.4](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) that creates dynamically elements inside a div with `layout horizontal` [polymer shadow](https://github.com/Polymer/layout/blob/master/shadow-layout.html) classes, so my code looks like:

```html
<div class='layout horizontal'>
     <div ng-repeat="elements in forms"></div>
</div>
```

So when a new element is created, it's rendered at the right side of the previous one and it gets the focus. So far so good. But when it appears, it does it **suddenly**. The scrollbar, if needed, appears and it's set to the new element without any transition, what looks a bit chaotic. I would like that to add a smooth movement of the scrollbar.

I add an sketch of the situation:
[image]

I think I should:

1. Avoid the movement to the new element.
2. Move the scrollbar slowly from the previous point to the new one.

Do you know if there's any polymer or angular transition able to do this?
Any idea to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know angular and ng-repeat but I think logical as necessary it would be as in native way;

```
.horizontal
{
   width: 100%; /* or your widht pereference */
   overflow-x: scroll;
}

 /* float cleaner for inside elements */
.horizontal:before{ clear: both; content: " " }
.horizontal:after{ clear: both; content: " " }

.horizontal .elements.in
{
   float: left; /* horizontally to knee */
   width: 500px; /* or your inside elements width pereference */
}
```